# ASCII Character Jumble

Tags: code-golf, string, number, printable-ascii, base-conversion

Write a program that takes as its input a string consisting of printable characters (ASCII 20-7E) and an integer `n` in [2,16] and performs the following modification to the string.

- Each character in the string is converted to its ASCII code (the examples given are in hexadecimal, though base 10 is also acceptable).
- The ASCII codes are converted to base `n` and are concatenated together.
- The new string is split every other character. If there are an odd number of characters, then the last character is removed entirely.
- Printing ASCII codes (in base 16) are converted back into their characters, whereas non-printing ASCII codes are removed.
- The resulting string is printed.

**Test case**

*Input*

```
Hello, World!
6
```

*Steps*

```
Hello, World!
48 65 6C 6C 6F 2C 20 57 6F 72 6C 64 21
2002453003003031125222330331030024453
20 02 45 30 03 00 30 31 12 52 22 33 03 31 03 00 24 45
```

The output of this program is  `E001R"31$E`.

---

This is code golf, so standard rules apply. Shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: This encoding algorithm can be useful for sending secret messages!

Comment: Gotta do this sometime!

Comment: @ΚριτικσιΛίθος while the program works for every possible input string, not every output string is unique. For example, in base `7`, the string `J` would go through the steps `J` -> `50` -> `101` -> `10` -> `(no output)`, as would the string `K` or `L`.

Comment: Like @Eridan said, this is a lossy encryption since odd sequences get the last character lopped off. Though I'm sure to the ignorant observer it could be a snarky way of communicating :)

Comment: Can a function be written?

Comment: Step 1 is confusing - no need to convert chars to hexadecimal - in the example: `H` is ASCII 72 (decimal) or 48 (hex), but what I need is 200 (base 6). All the row 2 in the example is useless and confusing in my opinion

Comment: @edc65 You're right about not needing the hex codes, though that's what I tend to prefer when looking at an ASCII table. I have changed the instructions, but the examples are how I would look at the problem.

Answer (score 5):

## Pyth - 22 bytes

Hope to golf a lot more, pretty straightforward.

```
sfq3l`TmCid16csjRQCMz2
```

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=sfq3l%60TmCid16csjRQCMz2&input=Hello%2C+World%21%0A6&debug=0).

Comment: ``q3l`T`` is wonderful.

Comment: Shouldn't `fgTd` be enough?

Answer (score 4):

## CJam, 33 bytes

```
q~:i\fb:~0+2/W<Gfb:c' ,-'ÿ),127>-
```

Takes input in the form `6 "Hello, World!"`. [Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q~%3Ai%5Cfb%3A~0%2B2%2FW%3CGfb%3Ac'%20%2C-'%C3%BF)%2C127%3E-&input=6%20%22Hello%2C%20World!%22)

[See Dennis's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62979/8478) for a similar but better solution with a nice explanation.

Answer (score 3):

## Bash + common linux utils, 118

```
printf %s "$1"|xxd -p|sed -r "s/../\U& /g;y/ /n/;s/^/dc -e$2o16i/e;s/../& /g;s/ .$//;"|xxd -rp|sed 's/[^[:print:]]//g'
```

Comment: I think you could shorten `printf %s "$1"` into `echo -n "$1"` to save 2 bytes

Comment: @Aaron That works until the input string is `-e`.  [Try `echo -n "-e"`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20003602/how-do-i-echo-e/20005227#20005227)

Comment: Damn, nicely spotted !

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 137 <s>147</s>

Using the most verbose functions available in JavaScript

```js
f=(s,b)=>alert(s.replace(/./g,x=>x.charCodeAt().toString(b)).match(/../g).map(x=>(x=String.fromCharCode('0x'+x))<='~'&x>' '?x:'').join``)

// Just for test purpose, redefine alert()
alert=x=>document.write('<pre>'+x+'</pre>')

f('Hello, World!',6)
f('PORK',3)
```

Comment: I think you can save some bytes by using `[for(z of ...)if(...)...]` instead of `map(...).filter(...)`

Comment: @Ypnypn I did not found a way to use your hint (apart from using array comprehension that is ES7) but you pressed me to rethink it all. Thx. I hope you'll keep your +1 even if `x=>x>=` has gone

Comment: What's wrong with using ES7?

Comment: @Ypnypn I prefer an answer that can work even with subpar javascript engines <troll on>like Chrome</troll off>

Comment: @edc65 +1 because Chrome _is_ subpar! (Please don't lynch me internet!) But why have you opened `<troll on>` then closed `<troll off>`?

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 24 bytes

```
l:irifbe_2/{Gbc',32>&}/
```

Note that there is a DEL character (0x7F) between `'` and `,`. Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=l%3Airifbe_2%2F%7BGbc'%7F%2C32%3E%26%7D%2F&input=Hello%2C%20World!%0A6).

#### How it works

```
l:i                     Read a line from STDIN and cast each char to integer. 
   ri                   Read another integer (base) from STDIN.
     fb                 Convert each integer from line 1 to that base.
       e_2/             Flatten and split into chunks of length 2.
                        If the last chunk has only one element, it will get
                        converted into a control character, which will be
                        removed later.
          {         }/  For each digit pair:
           Gb             Convert the pair from base 16 to integer.
             c            Cast to character.
              ',          Push the string of ASCII characters up to '~'.
                32>       Remove the first 32 (control characters).
                   &      Intersect.
```

Comment: What about the DEL character...? It looks like you've worked around that, but I can't see it in your explanation!

Comment: StackExchange filters unprintable characters. The DEL character is only present in thr permalink, and invisible even there.

Comment: I mean... Delete is a control character, but is not one of the first 32 characters. _It is character number 127, 0x7F, for people who are not familiar with ASCII._

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question. Are you wondering how I filter it from the output?

Comment: Yes. Your code explanation doesn't seem to say how you filter the `DEL` character from the output.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 `,` pushes an exclusive range; `'<DEL>,` pushes the string of all ASCII characters with code points strictly below 127. `32>` removes the remaining control characters from that string, and `&` intersects the character on the stack with the generated string of printable ASCII characters. For each character, this gives either a singleton or an empty string.

Comment: Your explanation says it pushes them up to ~... :facepalm: Up to _and including_ `~`. Ok, I understand now. Thanks for taking the time to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, 118 bytes

```julia
f(s,n)=join(map(i->(c=string(Char(parse(Int,i,16))))^isprint(c),matchall(r"..",join(map(i->base(n,Int(i)),[s...])))))
```

Ungolfed:

```julia
function f(s::AbstractString, n::Integer)
    # Construct an array of ASCII codes in base n
    v = map(i -> base(n, Int(i)), [s...])

    # Join into a string and get all pairs, truncating
    # to an even length
    m = matchall(r"..", join(v))

    # Parse each pair as an integer in base 16, get the
    # character associated with that code point, convert
    # to a string, and include if it's printable
    x = map(i -> (c = string(Char(parse(Int, i, 16)))^isprint(c), m)

    # Join as a string and return
    return join(x)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

## TeaScript, 23 bytes

TeaScript is JavaScript for golfing

```
£lc¡T(y©K(2)ßC(P(l,16±µ
```

Relatively straight-forward but delightfully short. I can probably golf down a few more characters with some more operators. A few other new features might also be able to be used to cut down some bytes.

## Ungolfed && Explanation

```
x.l(#
    l.c().T(y)
).K(2)
.m(#
    C(
      P(l,16)
    )
).j``
```

Comment: I believe this is 23 *chars* (29 *bytes*) long.

Comment: @w0lf That would be with UTF-8 encoding but because all characters are less then 256 we can safely count them as one byte

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 134 bytes

```
Print@FromCharacterCode@Select[#~FromDigits~16&/@StringPartition[""<>ToCharacterCode@InputString[]~IntegerString~Input[],2],31<#<127&]
```

If a function is allowed:

#### Mathematica, 112 bytes

```
FromCharacterCode@Select[#~FromDigits~16&/@StringPartition[""<>ToCharacterCode@#~IntegerString~#2,2],31<#<127&]&
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby 92

```
->s,n{o=''
s.chars.map{|x|x.ord.to_s n}.join.scan(/../).map{|x|x>?2&&x<?8&&o<<x.to_i(16)}
o}
```

Online test [here](http://ideone.com/QBaJje).

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 174 bytes

```
def J(a,b,i=0):
 h=r=''
 B=lambda n,b:n*'x'and B(n/b,b)+chr(48+n%b+7*(n%b>9))
 for c in a:h+=B(ord(c),b)
 while i<len(h):v=int(h[i:i+2],16);r+=chr(v)*(31<v<127);i+=2
 print r
```

[Try it here](http://ideone.com/pXV5cH)

Not really the best tool for the job. Since Python has no convert-to-arbitrary-base function, I had to implement my own. That was fun, at least--particularly finding a [marginally] shorter expression for the digits than `"0123456789ABCDEF"[n%b]`. For iterating over two characters at a time, I found a `while` loop was slightly shorter than a functional approach.

181 bytes as a full program:

```
B=lambda n,b:n*'x'and B(n/b,b)+chr(48+n%b+7*(n%b>9))
a=raw_input()
b=input()
h=r=''
for c in a:h+=B(ord(c),b)
i=0
while i<len(h):v=int(h[i:i+2],16);r+=chr(v)*(31<v<127);i+=2
print r
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 13 bytes

```
C$vτHfṅǒHCkQ↔
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJzIiwiIiwiQyR2z4RIZuG5hceSSENrUeKGlCIsIiIsIkhlbGxvLCBXb3JsZCFcbjYiXQ==)

Answer (score 0):

### MATLAB, 103 bytes

```
function k(s,n),b=dec2base(s,n)';b(~cumsum(b-'0',1))='';c=base2dec(textscan(b,'%2c'),16)';char(c(c>31))
```

I've written a function *k* that takes a string *s* and an integer *n* as input. e.g.:

```
k('Hello, World!',6)
```

gives

```
 E001R"31$E
```

Most annoying thing I had to work around is leading zeros showing up when converting to base *n*. Getting these out of the array that was to be split after every 2nd character cost quite a lot of bytes. Not sure if it is possible to save any more bytes using this approach.

Answer (score 0):

### PHP - 286 bytes

Put the string in `$s` and the integer in `$b`.

```
<?php $s=$_GET["s"];$b;$m="array_map";echo implode($m(function($v){return ctype_print($v)?$v:"";},$m("chr",$m("hexdec",str_split(strlen(implode($a=$m(function($v){global$b;return base_convert($v,16,$b);},$m("dechex",$m("ord",str_split($s))))))%2==1?substr(implode($a),0,-1):$a,2)))));?>
```

Pass the value to `GET["s"]`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 26 bytes

```
ir[sp>lS<]>ry[puu' oy1G*]p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/z@zKLq4wC4n2CbWrqgyuqC0VF0hv9LQXSu24P9/j9ScnHwdhfD8opwURQA)

This code uses the `S` instruction to convert the codepoints to digits one input character at a time.  Then it just prints pairs of digits delimited with spaces from the accumulation stack.

```
ir
i                          - read input as codepoints
 r                         - reverse stack
  [      ]                 - for each input char/codepoint...
   sp                      - stash codepoint and delete
     >l                    - switch to accum stack, load codepoint
       S                   - convert codepoint to digits
        <                  - switch back to input stack
          >r               - switch to accum stack, reverse digits
            y[          ]  - loop until stack size is <2
              p            - delete loop iterator artifact
               uu          - print two digits
                 ' o       - print a space
                    y1G    - is the stack size >1?
                       *   - multiple to combine top two of stack
                         p - print iterator artifact
```