# Code 3k to Codee k

Tags: code-golf, source-layout

## Write some code...

Write a program that takes **no input** and outputs an integer `n` which is a multiple of `3`. So `n=3k`, where `k` is a positive integer.
**Double** the **last character** of your code.
Your code should then output `k`.

## Examples

Here is my program `hui#2(21+4)//lm`, which outputs `81`.
Because of that, `hui#2(21+4)//lmm` should output `27`.
or
If `p8$w2*8` outputs `9`, `p8$w2*88` should output `3`.

## Rules

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: Can it output `9.0` and `3.0`? (Taking square roots, so it automatically turns into a float. :P)

Comment: This is a less interesting version of [double the source, double the output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/132558/56656).  And that wasn't terribly interesting to begin with.

Comment: I've downvoted this as, even by my standards, this is far too trivial, solvable with basic subtraction or square rooting, as illustrated by a lot of the solutions so far.

Comment: @Shaggy then use your imagination! be creative instead of downvoting.Many people here gave some great answers.

Comment: @BillSteihn You don't understand - this is code golf. The goal is to find the shortest answer, not to be creative. The answer that Shaggy provided is a trivial way of achieving your answer, and will be the shortest way to solve this challenge in most languages.

Comment: @Qwerp-Derp you don't understand what I am really saying... Since this is code-golf only a very clever and creative answer can win! just look at the answers!

Comment: @BillSteihn But with a challenge this straightforward (at least, for languages with 1-byte builtins for mathematical functions), this is the approach that a lot of the answers here take, which is what Shaggy noted.

Comment: As @QwerpDerp said, this is code golf; creativity is, for the most part, not conducive to a healthy byte count.

Comment: Are we allowed to use a function instead of a program for verbose languages like Java or .NET C#?

Answer (score 41):

## Mathematica, 2 bytes

```
4!
```

4! returns 24
4!! returns 8

Comment: This one is _really_ cute :)

Answer (score 36):

### Many languages, 4 bytes

```
16-1
```

Outputs 15.

```
16-11
```

Outputs 5.

This is a CW answer [for many languages it works for](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11218/20260). Edit to add to the list:

- APL
- bc
- Dyvil
- Haskell
- I
- J
- Japt
- Javascript REPL
- Java REPL
- Julia REPL
- Mathematica
- Python REPL
- R REPL
- Ruby REPL
- Scala REPL
- Swift REPL
- TI-83/84 Basic

Comment: JavaScript (console only). But I'm not sure if it would be valid.

Comment: @ThePirateBay I think REPL answers are valid. This should work for Python too, in a REPL environment, right?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Yes, though they count as separate languages. i added both.

Comment: I suspect your list is going to get quite long for this one! Works in Japt (although you could replace `16` with a constant to save a byte).

Comment: Sage as well. :)

Comment: JShell 9 should also work

Comment: [k](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/39BM1/D/fwA) too :)

Answer (score 15):

## [Lost](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Lost), <s>52</s>, 18 bytes

```
\(@>>>
\>>%?
\(13$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8kvLvn/P0bDwc7OjivGzk7VnitGw9BY5f///7qBAA)

```
\(@>>>
\>>%?
\(13$$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8kvLvn/P0bDwc7OjivGzk7VnitGw9BYReX///@6gQA)

### Explanation

Lost is a language in which the start location and direction of the pointer are entirely random.  Thus making a deterministic program can be tough.

The code we want to execute is either `13$(@` or `13$$(@`.

- `31` pushes 3 and 1 to the stack
- `$` will swap them
- `$` will swap them back if present
- `(` will pop the top element
- `@` will halt and output

We want to insert the `$` at the end so we have to split this

```
\(@
v
\31$
```

The rest of this is a careful orchestration to make sure that every possible pointer executes this code and only this code.

Answer (score 10):

## [Operation Flashpoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Flashpoint:_Cold_War_Crisis) scripting language, 19 bytes

```
a="3";aa="1";hint a
```

**Outputs:**

[image]

```
a="3";aa="1";hint aa
```

**Outputs:**

[image]

Comment: Wow, just wow :D Anyway, can't you just `hint a,aa`?

Comment: @KeyWeeUsr You mean to output both at the same time? `hint format["%1\n%2", a, aa]` would do that (or `hint (a+"\n"+aa)` because they are strings), but I think outputting them separately illustrates the solution better here.

Comment: The screenshots are always entertaining now, you sniping a tank, eh?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Just observing it and the surroundings with my binoculars. It's way out of range for any anti-tank weapons I'd might be carrying, so I need to get closer, but first I must check that there's no enemy infantry around preventing me from doing so.

Comment: @Steadybox obviously you'd recommend this game, eh? Is it a steam game?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn It's my favourite game. However, its old and might not be for everybody, and most of the fun with it is modding it and making your own scenarios (or playing around with existing mods). You can find it on Steam with its re-release name "ARMA: Cold War Assault".

Comment: @Steadybox THIS IS ARMA?! I've heard such good things! I'll look into it.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn The ARMA series are sequels of this game. They (and the re-release of this game) are named differently, because the developer (Bohemia Interactive Studios) didn't own the name "Operation Flashpoint". That name is owned by the original publisher (Codemasters).

Comment: You should crop those images...

Answer (score 10):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
3ȷ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/4xPb//wE)

Outputs 3000. `3ȷ` is a numeric literal for 3000.

`3ȷȷ` outputs 1000: `3ȷ` is 3000, which is thrown away and replaced by `ȷ`, 1000.

This is the only two-byte solution, and it is optimal; I found it by trying every possible program.

Answer (score 9):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 2 bytes

```
5¬
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/9/00Jr//wE)

Repeating the last character: [`5¬¬`](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/9/00JpDa/7/BwA).

Explanation:

```
5¬
5   push 5
 ¬  subtract 2
```

Adding another `¬` causes 2 to be subtracted from 3, yielding 1.

Comment: Paradoc version: [`5«`](https://tio.run/##K0gsSkzJT/7/3/TQ6v//AQ "Paradoc – Try It Online"), [`5««`](https://tio.run/##K0gsSkzJT/7/3/TQ6kOr//8HAA "Paradoc – Try It Online") I hope you find this symbol choice more mnemonic — it was supposed to be one of its comparative strengths :)

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 9 bytes

```python
print 3&3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EwVjN@P9/AA) Prints 3.

```python
print 3&33
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EwVjN2Pj/fwA) Prints 1.

Comment: Also works with 3&7, 6&6, 7&3, 7&6, or 8^1

Comment: Shave off 6 bytes by using REPL

Answer (score 5):

## [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE), 2 bytes

This prints `3` and `6ee` prints `1`.

```
6e
```

**[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=6e&input=&warnings=0&hex=0)**

```
6ee
```

**[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=6ee&input=&warnings=0&hex=0)**

```
6  - Push 6.
 e - Floor halve.
   - Print Implicitly.
```

---

## How?

Not much to explain. The whole point of this solution is that:

[image] [image]

Answer (score 5):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 4 bytes

```
2_5+
```

Outputs `27`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/3yjeVPv/fwA)

```
2_5++
```

Outputs `9`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/3yjeVFv7/38A)

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
81½
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/C8NDe//8B)

Outputs 9.

```
81½½
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/C8NDeQ3v//wcA)

Outputs 3.

Comment: Is `½` really square root? I can't figure which is worse, the `½` or Actually's `¬`

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell, 8 bytes

```
gcd 3 21
```

Outputs `3`, and `gcd 3 211` outputs `1`.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
3Xr
```

Outputs 3.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fOKLo/38A)

```
3Xrr
```

Outputs 1.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fOKKo6P9/AA)

Comment: `5Í`, maybe? :P

Comment: `тg` too ;)...?

Answer (score 4):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 6 bytes

Works by changing the path based on cubes with different edge sizes.  None of that tricky math stuff.  The starting numbers could be also 1 3 or 2 6

```
39O@W@
```

Cubified

```
  3
9 O @ W
  @
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5Nyqz4/9/Y0t8h3OH/fwA)

Only executes `9O@` which is Push 9, Output as number, Halt.

```
39O@W@
```

Cubified

```
    3 9
    O @
W @ @ . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
    . .
    . .
```

This now executes `W3O@`, which is Left shift, Push 3, Output as number, Halt.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5Nyqz4/9/Y0t8h3MHh/38A)

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 13 bytes

```
PrimeOmega@27
```

Not the shortest solution but y'know...

Answer (score 3):

## C, <s>60</s> 45 bytes

*Thanks to @nwellnhof for saving 15 bytes!*

```
#define AA"5");}
#define A"1"AA
main(){puts(A
```

[Outputs 15](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/185JTUtMy9VwdFRyVRJ07qWCy6gZKjk6MiVm5iZp6FZXVBaUqzh@P8/AA)

```
#define AA"5");}
#define A"1"AA
main(){puts(AA
```

[Outputs 5](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/185JTUtMy9VwdFRyVRJ07qWCy6gZKjk6MiVm5iZp6FZXVBaUqzh6Pj/PwA)

Comment: `#define AA"5");} #define A"1"AA main(){puts(A`

Comment: @nwellnhof Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## Polyglot, [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E) / [2sable](https://github.com/Adriandmen/2sable), 3 bytes

This one prints `9`. `81tt` prints `3`.

```
81t
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fwrDk/38A)**
**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MypOTMpJ/f/fwrDk/38A)**

```
81tt
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fwrCk5P9/AA)** **[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MypOTMpJ/f/fwrCk5P9/AA)**

Answer (score 3):

## [Befunge-98](https://github.com/catseye/FBBI), 6 bytes

```
<q%5b'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/36ZQ1TRJ/f9/AA)

Outputs via exit code.

Explanation: On program start the IP is immediately sent leftwards, so it wraps to the right end and executes commands from right to left. So, in this program, it encounters `'b5%`, which pushes 98, the value of the character `b`, and then computes the remainder of 98 when divided by 5, which is 3. Finally, with `q`, it quits with this exit code.

With the last character doubled, it encounters `''b5%`, which pushes the value of the character `'` but then immediately pushes `b`, which is 11. It then computes the remainder of 11 when divided by 5, which is 1, and quits with this exit code.

Comment: "It then computes the remainder of 12 when divided by 5, which is 1, and quits with this exit code." - I think you mean 11...

Comment: You're right, fixed

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 4 bytes

This prints `9`. `x8 11` prints `3`.

```
x8 1
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/v8JCwfD/fwA)**

```
x8 11
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/v8JCwdDw/38A)**

---

## How?

```
x8 1  - Full program.

x     - Bitwise XOR.
 8 1  - Of 8 and 1.
      - Implicitly print.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Befunge-98 (PyFunge)](https://pythonhosted.org/PyFunge/), 5 bytes

```
[q/3g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//@PLtQ3Tv//HwA)

Outputs via exit code.

#### Explanation

First, the IP hits the "turn left" instruction (`[`) twice, which wraps it back around to the back of the code, going right.

The "get" instruction (`g`) takes the first 2 values and pushes the ASCII value of the character at that x and y position. The first time it is executed, there are only zeros on the stack, meaning we get the value 91. If we don't double the `g`, we divide 91 by 3, with integer division, truncating it to 30, which is returned.

If we do duplicate the `g`, it gets the ASCII value at (0, 91), which isn't anywhere near the code. Because the grid is initialized to be filled with spaces, this returns the value 32. if we integer divide by 3, we get 10, one third of 30.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 16 bytes

```
a=3;aa=1;print a
```

outputs 3

```
a=3;aa=1;print aa
```

outputs 1

Answer (score 1):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 5 bytes

```
é52ñ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v///BKU6PDGyX@//@vWwYA)

Outputs 3

```
é52ñ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v///BKU6PDGyUk/v//r1sGAA)

Outputs 1

Answer (score 1):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 6 bytes

```
3>1<<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/9/YztDGxu7/fwA)

Outputs `3`.

With the second character duplicated:

```
3>1<<>>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/9/YztDGxs7u/38A)

Outputs `1`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Recursiva](https://github.com/officialaimm/recursiva), 5 bytes

```
+16-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pNLi0qzixL/P9f29BM1/D/fwA)

- Ripped off from [Many languages solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140592/59523), only a byte more since Recursiva is prefix and `-` sign and subtract operator are the same. This is actually adding `16` and `-1`.

## Other solution:

## [Recursiva](https://github.com/officialaimm/recursiva), 10 bytes

```
Y_+B5A3IH1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pNLi0qzixL/P8/Ml7bydTR2NPD8P9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

This one outputs `3`. By doubling the last character, you get `1`.

```
HḞ
6Ç
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/j4Y55XGaH2///BwA)**

```
HḞ
6ÇÇ
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/j4Y55XGaH2w@3//8PAA)**

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), 3 bytes

Still on the hunt for a 2 byte solution.

`#Q` is 81 and `¬` is square root, which gives `9`. Adding another `¬` at the end gives `3`

```
#Q¬
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=I1Gs&input=)

```
#Q¬¬
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=I1GsrA==&input=)

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 6 bytes

```
",n;c!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X0knzzpZ8f9/AA)

```
",n;c!!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X0knzzpZUfH/fwA)

#### Explanation

```
",n;c!  : Put each character onto the stack;
          [110, 59, 99, 33]
 ,n;    : Divide the top two stack items, print as a number and end.
          99/33 = 3
```

---

```
",n;c!! : Put each chat onto the stack;
          [110, 59, 99, 33, 33]
 ,n;    : Divide the top two stack items, print as a number and end.
          99/33 = 3
```

Comment: This ports to [Runic](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/z9BR8U6WfH/fwA) and doesn't feel worth posting as its own answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt/wiki/Codepage)

```
9₃
```

Returns 9/3

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f/f8lFT8///AA)

---

```
9₃₃
```

Returns (9/3)/3

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f/f8lFTMxD9/w8A)

---

Alternatively, also 2 bytes:

```
6₂
```

This works due to Python 2's integer division

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 5 bytes

```
-16 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X9fQTMHw/38A)

- Yet another rip from [many languages answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140592/59523)

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 6 bytes

This one prints `15`. The other version prints `5`.

```
Ｉ⁻¹⁶¦¹
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARsA5P9jaGFyY29hbP//77yp4oG7wrnigbbCpsK5//8)**

```
Ｉ⁻¹⁶¦¹¹
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR0A4v9jaGFyY29hbP//77yp4oG7wrnigbbCpsK5wrn//w)**

Answer (score 0):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), 2 bytes

```
ηᚠ
```

Outputs 3. Doubled, outputs 1.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0vNzP3//9z2h7MW/P8PAA)

[Doubled](https://tio.run/##y0vNzP3//9z2h7MWANH//wA)

Answer (score 0):

**Ruby, 5 bytes**

```
3/0b1
```

Division by one or three, written in binary.

Comment: This appears to be a code snippet and not a function or full program.

Answer (score 0):

## [RProgN 2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/RProgN-2), 2 bytes

```
6›
```

`6›` takes `6` and shifts it right. `110 -> 11` which gives 3. `6››` shifts 6 twice, which gives `110 -> 1`, or 1.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kyooyk/P0zX6/9/sUcOu//8B)

Answer (score 0):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 10 bytes

Feels cheap to just overwrite the `33` numeric literal, but it's the shortest way I know of to make this work in forth

```forth
: 33 1 ; 3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//WykYGysYKlgrGP/X@w8A)

outputs 3

```forth
: 33 1 ; 33
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//WykYGysYKlgDqf96/wE)

outputs 1

#### Explanation

```forth
: 33 1 ;  \ defines a new word 33 that puts a 1 on the stack.
          \ In forth explicit word definitions are parsed before numeric literals
```

Comment: This is in the wrong direction. You should output 3 for the first program and 1 for the second.

Comment: @WeijunZhou Good catch, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

## [Klein](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Klein) 0X0, 8 bytes

*Works in 000 (torus) and 010 (Klein bottle)*

```
\(@
\13$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y85Jzcz7/z9Gw4ErxtBY5f///waGBgA)

```
\(@
\13$$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y85Jzcz7/z9Gw4ErxtBYReX///8GhgYA)

## 1XX,  9 bytes

*Works in 100, 101, 110 and 111*

```
\>(@
\13$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y85Jzcz7/z/GTsOBK8bQWOX///@GBgYA)

```
\>(@
\13$$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y85Jzcz7/z/GTsOBK8bQWEXl////hgYGAA)