# Twice as long, half the price

Tags: code-golf, source-layout

Related: [I double the source, you double the output!](/q/132558/71806)

---

When *Steve Jobs* launched the iPhone 3G, the slogan said

> Twice as fast, half the price

I changed the word *fast* to *long* to better represent this challenge.

#### Objective

Write a program that outputs a non-zero, **even** integer. If the source code is doubled, the value of the output must be cut off by half.

To double the source in a Unix shell (with Core Utilites):

```
cat source.txt source.txt > doubled-source.txt
```

#### Rules & Requirements

Now the requirement has changed and the task has been even more challenging!

- You must build **a full program**.
- The initial source is **no longer required** to be at least 1 byte long. An empty program qualifies as long as the output is correct.
- Both the integers must be in base 10 (outputting them in any other base or with scientific notation is forbidden), and must **not** be zero. The integer is no longer required to be positive, so if you like a negative number, it's OK.
- Your program must not take input (or have an unused, empty input) and must not throw any error (compiler warnings are not considered errors). Exit code must be zero.
- Outputting the integers with trailing / leading spaces / newlines is allowed, as long as only one integer is output.
- You can't assume a newline between copies of your source. If you need one, **clarify it**. See the Unix shell command above.
- [Standard loopholes are forbidden.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061)

Because this is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest (original, undoubled) code in each language wins!

#### Extras

Please give description / explanation to your code if possible.

Comment: Must the old and new program be in the same language?

Comment: @tsh Definitely

Comment: By the way, zero byte answers to this question can't exist.

Comment: @WheatWizard This is _exactly_ the opposite.

Comment: @Arthur That is somewhat true but also misleading.  The only difference between this question and that is the operation involved.  I consider this a rather minor difference that doesn't add anything not already present in the original.

Answer (score 5):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 12 bytes

```
(()()[][{}])
```

Outputs 2. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X0NDU0MzOja6ujZW8/9/AA)

The doubled program outputs 1. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X0NDU0MzOja6ujZWE5n9/z8A)

#### Explanation

This code pushes 2 + stack height - top of stack.  Initially, this is 2 + 0 - (implicit) 0 = 2.  When this code is run again, it pops the existing 2 and pushes 2 + 1 - 2 = 1.

Comment: This is in fact a provably optimal solution.  I don't have the space for the complete proof in this comment but it's not very complex, feel free to ping me in chat for a complete proof.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <strike>35</strike> 34 bytes

Uses a concept similar to that of [Wheat Wizard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656/wheat-wizard) in the [double challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/132565/72350) with an [improvement](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140886/72350) I found to his original code. Here I use the fact that the length of the file is 34 bytes long. Meaning it is equal to 4 modulo 6. (`34%6 = 4`). The double source code would have a length of 68. And `68%6 = 2`, which is exactly what we want.

```python
print open(__file__,"a").tell()%6#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EIb8gNU8jPj4tMyc1Pl5HKVFJU68kNSdHQ1PVTPn/fwA)

[Double source code](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EIb8gNU8jPj4tMyc1Pl5HKVFJU68kNSdHQ1PVTJmwiv//AQ)

## Explanation

This opens the source code file in append mode

```python
open(__file__,"a")
```

We then find the current position in the file, this will be at the end of the file due to opening in append mode

```python
open(__file__,"a").tell()
```

We print this length modulo 6

```python
print open(__file__,"a").tell()%6
```

And add a comment, so that doubling the source code does not execute more code

```python
print open(__file__,"a").tell()%6#
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
¬‘
```

Outputs 2, **[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///QmkcNM/7/BwA)**

While

```
¬‘¬‘
```

Outputs 1, **[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///QmkcNM8DE//8A)**

#### How?

The default input to a monadic chain is zero...

```
¬‘   - Main link: no arguments
¬    - logical not -- not the implicit input of 0 to yield 1
 ‘   - increment   -- increment 1 to yield 2
     - implicit print if this is the end of the program, otherwise...
     ...
  ¬‘ - continues the monadic chain:
  ¬  - logical not -- not the 2 to yield 0
   ‘ - increment   -- increment 0 to yield 1
     - implicit print if this is the end of the program
```

---

The two byters:

```
Ị‘ - insignificant (abs(z)<=1); increment
Ṇ‘ - non-vectorising logical not; increment
```

would work too.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 7 bytes

```
2y1-+-N
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/9@o0lBXW9fv/38A)

Simple port of the [Brain-Flak answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140881/70424).

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

Outputs **4**

```
6rÍ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/frOhw7///AA)

**Doubled Source**

Outputs **2**

```
6rÍ6rÍ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/frOhwLwj//w8A)

**Explanation**

```
6      # push 6
 r     # reverse the stack (does nothing)
  Í    # subtract 2
```

With the doubled source we continue with

```
6      # push 6
 r     # reverse the stack (puts 4 on top)
  Í    # subtract 2
```

Comment: Does the `r` in the singlet form of your answer put 4 on top the top of the stack?

Comment: @TaylorScott: In the single form we only have a 6 on the stack so `r` does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

## sh, 50 bytes

```
#!/bin/sh
expr 200 / `wc -c $0 | cut -c 1-3`
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
®‘!İ©Ḥµ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARgA5/9qZWxsef//wq7igJghxLDCqeG4pMK1//8)

Outputs 2.

Duplicated Source:

```
®‘!İ©Ḥµ®‘!İ©Ḥµ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///QukcNMxSPbDi08uGOJYe2onH//wcA)

Outputs 1.