# Concatenated halting problem: no + no + ... = yes

Tags: code-challenge, source-layout, halting-problem

### Challenge

Write \$2 \le n \le 10\$ distinct, valid non-halting full programs in your language of choice. If all of them are concatenated in order, the resulting full program should be a valid halting program, but if any of them are left out, the result should still be a valid non-halting program.

More formally, write \$2 \le n \le 10\$ distinct programs \$P_1, P_2, \cdots, P_n\$ in a language \$L\$ of your choice, which satisfy the following property:

- \$P_1 P_2 \cdots P_n\$ (where \$XY\$ means string concatenation of two programs \$X\$ and \$Y\$) is valid full program in \$L\$ and, given no input, halts in finite time.
- If you delete any of \$1 \le x \le n-1 \$ program segments (\$P_i\$'s where \$1 \le i \le n\$) from the above, the result is still a valid full program in \$L\$, but does not halt in finite time.

  - In other words, any nonempty proper subsequence of \$P_1 P_2 \cdots P_n\$ should be a valid non-terminating program in \$L\$.

A program is *valid* if a compiler can successfully produce an executable or an interpreter finishes any pre-execution check (syntax parser, type checker, and any others if present) without error. A valid program is *halting* if the execution finishes for any reason, including normally (end of program, halt command) or abnormally (any kind of runtime error, including out-of-memory and stack overflow). The output produced by any of the programs does not matter in this challenge.

For example, a three-segment submission `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` is valid if

- `foobarbaz` halts in finite time, and
- each of `foo`, `bar`, `baz`, `foobar`, `foobaz`, and `barbaz` does not halt in finite time in the same language. (The behavior of `barfoo` or `bazbar` does not matter, since the segments are not in order.)

The score of your submission is the number \$n\$ (the number of program segments). The higher score wins, tiebreaker being code golf (lower number of bytes wins for the same score). It is encouraged to find a general solution that works beyond \$n = 10\$, and to find a solution that does not read its own source code (though it is allowed).

Comment: What if it halts because the interpreter times out?

Comment: @Ausername If the interpreter itself stops running after certain amount of time, then every program is halting by definition, and you cannot use it for this challenge. TIO timeout is a different thing, and it should be ignored (if a program would run forever assuming TIO timeout wasn't there, it is a valid non-halting program).

Comment: Ok. I meant TIO timeout.

Comment: does a background job in bash count as still running?

Comment: @Jonah If the program terminates in the view of the OS (i.e. the exit code is returned in finite time), I see it as halting.

Comment: Why do the programs have to be distinct?  I'm not complaining just curious as to the rationale.

Comment: @WheatWizard I don't have a strong rationale for that. Just that people will have to work harder to find a solution.

Comment: It just occurred to me that it's impossible to do this in a [concatenative language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenative_programming_language), because if `P1 + ... + P(n-1)` diverges then the concatenation of that with `P(n)` necessarily also diverges.

Answer (score 29):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 10 programs, 299 bytes

```javascript
(A=_=>setTimeout(A,B=_=>0))();
(B=_=>setTimeout(B,C=_=>0))();
(C=_=>setTimeout(C,D=_=>0))();
(D=_=>setTimeout(D,E=_=>0))();
(E=_=>setTimeout(E,F=_=>0))();
(F=_=>setTimeout(F,G=_=>0))();
(G=_=>setTimeout(G,H=_=>0))();
(H=_=>setTimeout(H,I=_=>0))();
(I=_=>setTimeout(I,J=_=>0))();
(J=_=>setTimeout(J,A=_=>0))()
```

- [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xcm5CgIxFAXQ30ngCvYyQvaltpdBU4ygI0709yM28rjtObf5M2@X1/Lsu8d6bWMoM52n49b6abm39d2Vgf3JXmulD8rSWjixjtbBi/W0HkFsoA2IYiNtRBKbaBOy2EybUcQW2oIqttJWmP@O8QU)
- [Try it online with second one dropped!](https://tio.run/##Xcm9CoMwFAbQ10ngE7oXhdT8z@5F2gwKVjHR1490kctdz5nHc8yffdpK81u/qVah2nfb5VSGaUnrUYTC6y8PKYV8ip5tD01Ws9UwZA1bA0vWsrVwZB1bB0/Ws/UIZAPbgEg2so1Q99Z6AQ)
- [Try it online with second one left!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f9fw8k23tauOLUkJDM3Nb@0RMNJxxkkYqCpqaFp/f8/AA)

Line breaks are added for readability. They are not a part of any programs.

Node.js will keep running if there is any timers been scheduled, and halt as soon as timer callback queue is cleared.

The order of these programs does not matter. After append an extra `;` to the last one, you may shuffle them and it still meets the requirement of this challenge. It halts as long as you collected all 10 programs, and never halts if anyone is missing. You may also duplicate some programs here, and it works same as the program appears only once. :)

Comment: Whoa, how does it even work?!

Comment: @Bubbler Node.js will keep running if any timer is on the fly, and halt if timer callback queue is cleared.

Comment: This is ingenious.

Comment: is there a way, in javascript, to generate the script to be executed? if so, as your script has lots of redundancy, it could be shortened a lot ? (in a nutshell:   generate lines A-J, execute generated code). edit: nevermind, the OP asks for 10 disctinct programs. But then : maybe have 1 program accepting 2 parameters, and the 10 distinct programs all call that one with 2 different parameter pairs? [not sure if it would fit the criteria]

Comment: @OlivierDulac no it would not, it would mean it would have to depend on other code...

Answer (score 20):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 56 bytes, 10 programs

```sh
until wc<<Q|grep 36
yes
yes;yes yes	yes yes ;yes
yes	yes
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P@/NK8kM0ehPNnGJrAmvSi1QMHYjKsytRiErYFYAYg5obSCNVQCJPD/PwA)

The first and most important program is:

```sh
until wc<<Q|grep 36
```

Each `yes` is part of one of the other programs.

[y it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P@/MrWYC4itgVgBiDmhtII1VAIk8P8/AA) (note: TIO kills the program very quickly because `yes` produces over 128 KB of output, but if you ran it elsewhere it would never halt)

[Tre!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P@/NK8kM0ehPNnGJrAmvSi1QMHYlKsytRiErTmBxP//AA)

### Explanation

- `<<Q`: heredoc; takes the rest of the script starting from the next line, as a string
- `wc`: output line, word, and character numbers
- `|grep 36`: and search for the string `36` in that output
- `until` : repeat this command until it succeeds

If all 10 programs are present, then there will be exactly 36 characters in the output of `wc` and the `grep` will succeed, so the loop will halt.

If the first program is removed, the remainder of the script will be interpreted as code instead of as a string in the heredoc, and `yes` will never halt.

All the weird whitespace around each `yes` is to make them all distinct and remain as short as possible (mostly 4 bytes).

If any of the `yes` programs is removed, there won't be a `36` in the output so the `until` will loop forever.

### Notes

- `yes` is intended to output `y` indefinitely so it can be piped into an interactive program that asks yes-or-no questions, but in this case it doesn't matter what it outputs
- `<<Q` actually only outputs the contents until the first line containing only `Q`, but there is no such line, so it just goes until the end of the file
- The exact splitting of the program is as follows; a `#` is used to separate each one here

```sh
until wc<<Q|grep 36
#yes

#yes;#yes #yes  #yes# yes# ;yes#
yes#    yes
```

Notice all the quirky whitespace, and there's a tab in there somewhere.

One of the programs is  `;yes`; it could just be `;yes` with no space, except in the case the only remaining programs are `yes;;yes`: zsh would throw a syntax error because `;;` is treated as one token instead of two semicolon command separators.

---

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 107 bytes, 10 programs

```sh
while 1=u
while 1+=i
while 1+=l
while 1+=t
while 1+=in
while 2=e
while 2+=x
while 2+=i
while 2+=t
until b$@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P@/PCMzJ1XB0LaUC8rSts1EMHMQzBIkBXlQtpFtKoylbVuBYGYimCVcpXklmTkKSSoO//8DAA)

[Try it onlin](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P@/PCMzJ1XB0LaUC8rSts1EMHMQzBIkBXlQtpFtKoylbVuBYGYimCX//wMA)

[Tryine!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P@/PCMzJ1XB0LaUC8rSts2EMo20bSsQTCTREq7SvJLMHIUkFYf//wE)

[nline!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P@/PCMzJ1XByDaVC8rStq1AMDMRzBKu0rySzByFJBWH//8B)

Each line is a program.

### Explanation

The idea is to use an infinite loop (well, 10 nested infinite loops), but, over the course of the 10 programs, construct and execute a string that will exit the loops.

If any program is removed, the string will no longer be a snippet that correctly exits, and the program will continue to loop.

The code to halt is built up by `1=u` `1+=i` etc. The string `uiltin` is stored in `$1`, and `exit` is stored in `$2`. Then, `$@` represents all the assigned numeric variables; a `b` is prepended to those to make `builtin exit`, which is executed and halts the program.

### Notes

- All the loops have no body - the code is entirely in the condition. Zsh seems not to care, though.
- The challenge states:

> A program is *valid* if [...] an interpreter finishes any pre-execution check (syntax parser, type checker, and any others if present) without error.

Despite producing lots of errors, the program(s) meet these criteria because they only occur at *runtime*. (that kind of comes with the territory when golfing in zsh)

- The `b` is prepended at execution instead of being made part of the string build-up, because it prevents the program where only `2` gets assigned to from halting - it will always result in `bexit` instead of `exit` (this is essentially a problem of irreducibility). There are also some substrings of `uiltin exit` that might be valid commands, which could end the `until` loop, but none exist once a `b` is prepended.
- `builtin` is a pre-command modifier that disambiguates in case `exit` is a user-defined function, but in this case it serves only to get us to 10 programs of which none can be removed.
- `in` is appended in one go instead of `i` and `n` separately because the 10 programs must be distinct, and `1+=i` is already used.
- For the first assignments to `1` and `2`, we can use `=` instead of `+=` to save a byte.

Answer (score 14):

## [Befunge-93](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), <s>25</s> 22 bytes (10 programs)

```
12+3+4+5+6+7+8+"#"`#@_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/39BI21jbRNtU20zbXNtCW0lZKUHZIf7/fwA)

Thanks JoKing for the suggestion (-3 bytes).

**Exaplanation**

The programs are:

```
1     Push 1
2     Push 2, pop two value and push the sum
+     Pop two value and push the sum
3+    Push 3, pop two value and push the sum
4+    Same with 4
5+    ...
6+
7+
8+
"#"`#@_    Last program, it will halt if the stack has a number >35 in it:
           "-"        Push 35
           `          Pop two value, compare, push 1 if greater than 35
           #          Skip the next char (v)
           @          End program
           _          Pop one value, go left if 1, right otherwise
```

The first 9 programs cannot halt, because there is no halt instruction.
The last program takes a number from the stack, and compares it to 35: if it is greater than 35 (the sum is 36), then will halt the program; otherwise, it will let the PC run right, which will repeat the program and loop forever.

Removing any combination of program 1 to 9 will make the sum to be less than 36, so the program will never halt (comparison will always fail).

In theory, it can be extended by adding more number, and changing the value of the comparison in the last program (depending on the size available in your Befunge implementation).

---

## [Befunge-93](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), <s>63</s> 73 bytes (10 programs)

```
 v
v>v
v >v
v  >v
v   >v
v    >v
v     >v
v      >v
v       >v
v       v@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/X6GMq8wOiBXABJSEUXAawUBiITPLHP7/BwA)

Thanks NickKennedy for the fix.

**Explanation**

Each line is a program.

The first 9 lines (i.e. programs) are redirecting the PC down. Since there is no end of program instruction, they will loop forever.

The 10th line is redirecting the PC down, followed by an halt program (@) instruction. If this is executed alone, the PC will loop in the vertical direction forever.

When all together, the PC will be able to get to the @ and halt the program.

Removing any one line will break the flow and will leave the PC loop forever vertically.

It can actually be expanded to 25 programs (which is the limit of the 80x25 code size of the befunge) by just adding more `v  >v` lines with the appropriate indentation.

If you use an implementation of befunge without the 80x25 limit, then it can be exdended indefinitely.

Comment: Does this work? https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/X6GMq8wOiBXABJSEUXAawUBiITPLHP7/BwA

Comment: Actually @DLosc’s suggestion seems to work and doesn’t cost bytes

Comment: When thinking about it, I have totally forgotten the removal of the first line (facepalm). I think the idea from @NickKennedy is closer to what I initially wanted to achieve, so I'll follow it.

Comment: could the last program be `","\`#@_` instead? With that you could also start splitting some of the other programs up into one byte each, as long as it isn't possible to exceed some constant that you're comparing to

Comment: Thanks, that is shorter than my last program and works as well. Also true, I might split one program in two `2` / `+` and remove one.

Comment: The second's really nice and elegant, +1!

Answer (score 12):

## JavaScript, 10 programs / 271 bytes

*Saved 12+ bytes per program thanks to @tsh*

This is similar to the method used by @darrylyeo in [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/222929/58563).

```javascript
o={get g(){while(k);},set go(_){k--;}};k=9;o.g
o={get g(){for(;;)0}};o.g
o={get g(){for(;;)1}};o.g
o={get g(){for(;;)2}};o.g
o={get g(){for(;;)3}};o.g
o={get g(){for(;;)4}};o.g
o={get g(){for(;;)5}};o.g
o={get g(){for(;;)6}};o.g
o={get g(){for(;;)7}};o.g
o={get g(){for(;;)8}};o.g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/37Y6PbVEIV1Dszotv0jD2lrToLbWOl8v/f9/AA) (non-halting)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/37Y6PbVEIV1Ds7o8IzMnVSNb07pWpxgklK8Rr1mdratrXVtrnW1raZ2vl46kOi2/SMPaWtMAKIlVwhCXhBEuCWNcEia4JExxSZjhkjDHJWEBkfj/HwA) (halting)

Comment: The programs should be distinct.

Comment: @Bubbler Missed that rule entirely. Now fixed.

Comment: 279 bytes: `o={get g(){while(k);},set go(x){k--}};k=9;o.go={get g(){while(1);}};o.go={get g(){while(2);}};o.go={get g(){while(3);}};o.go={get g(){while(4);}};o.go={get g(){while(5);}};o.go={get g(){while(6);}};o.go={get g(){while(7);}};o.go={get g(){while(8);}};o.go={get g(){while(9);}};o.g`

Comment: @tsh Nice! I (Incidentally, this is the very first time I see the _Setter must have exactly one formal parameter_ error when trying to omit it.)

Comment: That's a cool use of the setter!

Comment: From the idea of `for(;;);` you can write `for(;;)1` (without `;`) to `for(;;)9`: `o={get g(){for(;k;);},set go(_){k--;}};k=9;o.go={get g(){for(;;)1}};o.go={get g(){for(;;)2}};o.go={get g(){for(;;)3}};o.go={get g(){for(;;)4}};o.go={get g(){for(;;)5}};o.go={get g(){for(;;)6}};o.go={get g(){for(;;)7}};o.go={get g(){for(;;)8}};o.go={get g(){for(;;)9}};o.g`

Comment: @Arnauld Can you explain what the setter is doing?  I don't see `go` ever being called.

Comment: It might be possible to repeatedly call the getter as a recursive function which never halts, but only recall if k is truthy.

Comment: @Jonah The functions prefixed by `get` and `set` are called whenever the corresponding object properties are read or write respectively. [Here](https://tio.run/##ZcqxCsMgFEDR/X3F26KkDbTN9ug3uOooiYglaFBJh5BvtzZ0aMh673npRachujlffRhNKQKfuAKiNRkl47jiEHwKk@mmYFkTjR6dtygbTrhdKkwVKuZP8h1d/kq1S9gI4P/fOIHoJB3ifY/qGB81tu3J9r@sqJQP) is an example.

Comment: @Arnauld I think there is a typo somewhere. The code in the answer is not the same as in the Try it Online. Besides, the property `go` is never set in the current code, so I don't think this can work.

Comment: @Vincent As explained in the challenge, what is actually executed is a concatenation of some of or all the 10 programs.

Comment: @Vincent These 'lines' are concatenated into one. So the `o.g` and the end of a line is concatenated with the `o` starting the next one, making most of this program an attempt to set `o.go`, which decrements k. The fine segment gets `o.g` running the initial while loop, which halts only if all segments are present (the others are ignored as the setter for `o.go` ignores them). If the first segment is missing, `o.g` has an infinite loop instead.

Comment: @Arnauld I've used JS getters and setters before.  The specific part eluding me here is that I don't see any place where the setter is ever called.  I see the `o.g` instances that would invoke the getters, but nothing that would invoke the `go` setter.  What am I missing?

Comment: @Jonah When concatenated, the lines form `o.go` using the `o.g` from one and the `o` from the second, causing all statements but the first to try to assign `o.go`. The final one gets `o.g` starting the loop.

Comment: @jaxad0127 Ah... I missed that the linebreaks were just for readability.  Very clever!

Answer (score 12):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 10 programs, 188 bytes

```javascript
for(b=('a'in this);!b;);
for(c=this.b;!c;);
for(d=this.c;!d;);
for(e=this.d;!e;);
for(f=this.e;!f;);
for(g=this.f;!g;);
for(h=this.g;!h;);
for(i=this.h;!i;);
for(j=this.i;!j;);
for(var a;!this.j;);
```

[Try it online! (all, halts)](https://tio.run/##Lcg9DoMwDAbQq@AJGNq50icO4/w7Q0EB5fqpUvuNr3Ln2ze5nlf/jJHOtrljW3mV7/IUuXeQw475/pjxdiBvE3Q8KNhEnQCKNkkngpJN1kmgbFN0MqjYiE4BiU3VEVC16dwWBv173hg/)

[Try it online! (not all, does not halt)](https://tio.run/##Lcg7DoQwDAXAq@AKKJYa6YnDOD/iFOwqoFw/q2BPOYUb377K7/m0vff0rYs7lplnuaYny72CHFaM98eIzYG8TdDxoGATdQIo2iSdCEo2WecEZRvRySCxKToCKjaN68Sgt8f1/gc)

Javascript hoists the definition of `a` to the top of the scope, so even though it is defined later `'a' in this` returns `true`.

Comment: Maybe first time to see `var` keyword in code-golf for me

Answer (score 10):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 10 programs, 23 bytes

- `Wn17l"`
- `#`
- `#1`
- `#2`
- `#3`
- `#4`
- `#5`
- `#6`
- `#7`
- `#8`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PzzP0DxHSVnZUNlI2VjZRNlU2UzZXNni/38A)

#### How it works

With all programs present, the concatenation is equivalent to this halting Python loop:

```python
while 17 != len("##1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8"):
    pass
```

If the first program is present but another is missing, the string will no longer have length 17 and the loop will run forever.

If the first program is missing but another present, the concatenation begins with `#`, which loops a block until an error is raised (which will never happen):

```python
while True:
    try:
        while True:
            try:
                print(1)
                while True:
                    try:
                        print(2)
                        while True:
                            try:
                                print(3)
                                while True:
                                    try:
                                        print(4)
                                        while True:
                                            try:
                                                print(5)
                                                while True:
                                                    try:
                                                        print(6)
                                                        while True:
                                                            try:
                                                                print(7)
                                                                while True:
                                                                    try:
                                                                        print(8)
                                                                    except Exception:
                                                                        break
                                                            except Exception:
                                                                break
                                                    except Exception:
                                                        break
                                            except Exception:
                                                break
                                    except Exception:
                                        break
                            except Exception:
                                break
                    except Exception:
                        break
            except Exception:
                break
    except Exception:
        break
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like there is a way to make something using [one of the built-in variables](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PzwvKVVJWdlQ2UjZWNlE2VTZTNlcmev/fwA) to save a byte, as they all either don't work in the string or break the final loop program without costing another byte.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman You can’t just check the end of the string anyway, since you need to verify that *all* the components are there.

Comment: Ah, I missed that. Then this seems even more optimal than before!

Answer (score 8):

## [GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html), 10 programs, 99 bytes

```
:a s/^/A/
ba
```

```
:a :b bb
```

```
:b :c bc
```

```
:c :d bd
```

```
:d :e be
```

```
:e :f bf
```

```
:f :g bg
```

```
:g :h bh
```

```
:h :i bi
```

```
:i :j s/A//
Tj
```

### Explanation

[Meta consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5477/9486) lets sed programs take a single empty line as input (for, without that, sed simply won't do anything at all)

So, evidently, GNU sed will just let you define the same label multiple times, and all except the last one are ignored for execution purposes, which is nice for this challenge. Programs 1 through 9 each define a simple infinite loop (Program 1 does a bit more, which we'll get to in a minute)

```
:a ba
```

This defines a label `:a` and `ba` is effectively a `goto :a`. This program does nothing but loop forever. Then if we concatenate the second

```
:a ba :a :b bb
```

Now the `ba` goes to the *second* `:a` label, which effectively does nothing, and then we loop on `:b` forever. Each program "disarms" the prior one and them introduces its own loop.

Now, the final program

```
:i :j s/A//
Tj
```

First, we disarm the `:i` loop from the ninth program. Then we try to remove an `A` from the pattern space. The pattern space started out containing an empty string (remember, our input is a single empty line), so if we run Program 10 on its own, this substitute will *fail*. `Tj` is a conditional jump. It's a `goto :j` that only executes if the previous substitution *failed*. This is an infinite loop.

However, if Program 1 is in play, then the first thing we did was introduce an `A` at the beginning of the pattern space, which Program 10 happily removes and then the `Tj` doesn't execute since the substitution was successful.

The only way a concatenation of these programs can terminate is if the following conditions are met.

1. For N from 1 to 9, Program N contains an infinite loop trap that we can only escape if Program (N+1) is present.
2. Program 10 contains an infinite loop trap that we can only escape if Program 1 is present.

Hence, a nonempty concatenation terminates if and only if all ten programs are present.

Comment: Nice trick, and well explained too!

Comment: Nice solution. I think you can save a bit by using `G` instead of `s/^/A/` so that you can do `/./q` in the last program.

Answer (score 7):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 10 programs, 390 bytes

```bash
trap "while(($[a+=1]<55));do :;done" 0
trap "while(($[a+=2]<55));do :;done" 0
trap "while(($[a+=3]<55));do :;done" 0
trap "while(($[a+=4]<55));do :;done" 0
trap "while(($[a+=5]<55));do :;done" 0
trap "while(($[a+=6]<55));do :;done" 0
trap "while(($[a+=7]<55));do :;done" 0
trap "while(($[a+=8]<55));do :;done" 0
trap "while(($[a+=9]<55));do :;done" 0
trap "while(($[a+=10]<55));do :;done" 0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6QosUBBqTwjMydVQ0MlOlHb1jDWxtRUU9M6JV/BCkjkpSopGHBhKjMiTpkxccpMiFNmSpwyM@KUmROnzII4ZZbEKTM0wKLu/38A)

### How?

Each line contains an exit handler that contains a while loop.  The while loop will only halt if all the numbers 1..10 have been added to the variable $a.  If any lines are missing, then the while condition will be true and will not halt.

Comment: Doesn't each individual program need to be non-halting, whereas the variable assignments alone will halt?

Comment: @Jonah - there I fixed it (I think)

Comment: Nice, I was actually hoping you'd post a Bash answer.  I had a vague idea you could do something writing to and reading from named pipes (where maybe the final program, in the halting version, consumes them all), but wasn't able to make it work.

Comment: First thing that came to mind reading the OP, ninja'd me by 8 hours, or is that more like you Somu'd me! T_T

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 programs, <s>37</s> 35 bytes

```
L}n27$¿“¹1¿¹2¿¹3¿¹4¿¹5¿¹6¿¹7¿¹8¿¹9¿
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9@nNs/IXOXQ/kcNcw7tNDy0/9BOIxBhDCJMQIQpiDADEeYgwgJEWB7a//8/AA)

### Individual programs with explanation

```
L}n27$¿“ | While not 27, take the length of the right argument
¹1¿ | While 1 do the identity function
¹2¿ | While 2 do the identity function
¹3¿ | While 3 do the identity function
¹4¿ | While 4 do the identity function
¹5¿ | While 5 do the identity function
¹6¿ | While 6 do the identity function
¹7¿ | While 7 do the identity function
¹8¿ | While 8 do the identity function
¹9¿ | While 9 do the identity function
```

When the whole lot is concatenated together, this checks the length of the string between `“` and the end of the program is 27.

Any subsequence of these programs that does not include the first has an infinite while loop, while programs including the first one will only halt if all of the others are present so that the length is correct.

Answer (score 7):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), score 10, 11 bytes

```
90.123456!;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/39JAz9DI2MTUTNH6/38A)

At 1 point short of perfect this is as close as I can come in Gol><>.

The first 9 characters `90.123456` are all their own programs with `!;` being the only two byte program.

Since it contains the only halt instruction `!;` must be included to halt.  And since it has a `!` we can't simply get to `;` from the right.  The only other way to get to `;` is with the teleport `.`.  So `.` must be included as well.  If `.` is first it will pop two zeros and teleport to itself creating an infinite loop, so something must be present before it.  `0` causes the same type of infinite loop as before so `9` must be present as well.  Now `0,9` is a location that can never be filled since we have no newlines.  Thus any jump there creates an irretrievable infinite loop, we must have the `0` program as well.  Now we know the `.` must take us to `9,0`, and of course `;` must be the character there.  In order for this to happen we must have all the characters present.

This is the perfect score for Gol><> because if it were 10, 1 byte programs there would have to be a 1 byte program which halts on it's own.  As suggested by @Bubbler it might be possible to use source modification to insert a halt command, however since unknown commands crash Gol><> a `p` on it's own will override itself with a zero byte and halt with a crash.

Comment: Perfect score *might* be possible by conjuring the halt command out of thin air.

Comment: @Bubbler I think the only way to modify the source like that is `p` which unfortunately halts on it's own.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 10 programs, <s>206 196</s> 174 bytes

### Whole program: (174 bytes)

```python
i=1
while i:
 0#while 1:
 i=-8#while i:=2:
 i+=1#while i:=3:
 i+=1#while i:=4:
 i+=1#while i:=5:
 i+=1#while i:=6:
 i+=1#while i:=7:
 i+=1#while i:=8:
 i+=1#while i:=9:
 i+=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P9PWkKs8IzMnVSHTikvBQBnCNgSyM211LZRhUrZGIBFtW0OEiDGGiAmGiCmGiBmGiDmGiAWGiCVU5H9BUWZeiYZSSEaqQkFRfnpRYq5CRmKxQlpmXmZxRmqKkuZ/AA)

### Program 1: (16 bytes)

```python
i=1
while i:
 0#
```

### Program 2: (14 bytes)

```python
while 1:
 i=-8#
```

### Program 3 to 9: (18 char each)

```python
while i:=2:
 i+=1#
```

...

```python
while i:=8:
 i+=1#
```

### Program 10: (17 char)

```python
while i:=9:
 i+=1
```

### How it works:

- we set i to 1
- In the first program: `while i: 0` if `i` is not equal to `0` (wich is True at the start) we loop into the program. Otherwise the program finish.
- In the second program, if the first program is missing, `while 1` will loop indefinitely. We assign `i` to -8. If the second program is missing, `i` will always be strictly positive and the program will loop indefinitely
- Then we increment `i` by `1` inside the first while loop and comment to neutralize the next `while` statement
- If all 10 programs have been executed, `i` is now equal to `0` and the program stop. Otherwise, the program loops and `i` is set back to `-8` in the seacond loop or will continue to be incremented.

thanks to Bubbler, who pointed me that programs should all be differents, which ended saving me many bytes :p

Thanks to Wheat Wizard♦ which inspired me to improve my solution

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 10 programs, 127 bytes

The solution where the program reads its own source code I found is:

```python
while len(next(open(__file__)))<127:0#while 1:0#while 2:0#while 3:0#while 4:0#while 5:0#while 6:0#while 7:0#while 8:0#while 9:0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/vzwjMydVISc1TyMvtaJEI78AyIqPTwMKxsdramraGBqZWxkoQ1QZwllGcJYxnGUCZ5nCWWZwFsIUCzjL0srg/38A)

It is ... well ... a solution. Not clever, not even beautiful, but it is accepted so ...

#### First program :

```python
while len(open(__file__).read())<127:0#
```

exit if the program is at least 127 char long. Else loop

#### Program 2 to 9:

```python
while 1:0#
```

...

```python
while 8:0#
```

Just infinite loop

#### Program 10:

```python
while 9:0
```

Same but without comment

Comment: Programs should be distinct.

Comment: Oh? well I thnk I haven't learn to read. I will fix that

Comment: I think [this](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P9NW19CSqzwjMydVIdOKS8FSGca2NQRyM7VtjREiRhARI4SIMYaICYaIKYaIGYaIOYaIBYaIJVTkf0FRZl6JhlJIRqpCQVF@elFirkJGYrFCWmZeZnFGaoqS5n8A "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online") works and is shorter.

Comment: @WheatWizard thanks

Answer (score 6):

## [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), score 10, 19 bytes

```
0       @
+-*&|$`"'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P/fQAECHLi0dbXUalQSlNT//wcA)

Since Labyrinth programs operate by following the path formed by valid commands, solving this challenge in Labyrinth in its simplest form is about making sure the starting cell (the leftmost cell of the topmost row) is disconnected from the halt command `@` unless every piece appears in the program.

Whenever I thought I found something clever (which had 16 or 17 bytes), I was hit with a weird shortcut path. Also it doesn't help that a comment-only program isn't an infinite loop (the interpreter simply refuses to run it). So I decided to settle with this one, at least for now. (At least it's an improvement over the initial idea of 21 bytes)

```
0+-*&|$`"'
         @
```

---

The fragments are:

```
0       @\n
+
-
*
&
|
$
`
"
'
```

Since every comment-only program halts, every fragment must contain at least one valid command. To avoid memory issues, the commands to form the no-op path were chosen so that the stack size or the number size doesn't grow infinitely when repeated.

```
     All commands that pop and push something on the stack push a single 0
     when run as the first command, and effectively do nothing otherwise
0    Multiply the top by 10 and add 0 (0 * 10 + 0 = 0)
+    Add two numbers (0 + 0 = 0)
-    Subtract two numbers (0 - 0 = 0)
*    Multiply two numbers (0 * 0 = 0)
&    Bitwise & two numbers (0 & 0 = 0)
|    Bitwise | two numbers (0 | 0 = 0)
$    Bitwise ^ two numbers (0 ^ 0 = 0)
`    Negate top (-0 = 0)
"    No-op
'    Debugging no-op
```

It is obvious that we need the first program fragment (the only one containing `@`) to possibly halt. Then, since the `0` is the starting location, we need all the other 9 fragments to connect `0` to `@`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), score 10, 227 bytes

```hs
main=a;a=a where a=b;main=main;b=b where b=c;main=main;c=c where c=d;main=main;d=d where d=e;main=main;e=e where e=f;main=main;f=f where f=g;main=main;g=g where g=h;main=main;h=h where h=i;main=main;i=i where i=pure();main=main
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TclBCgIxDEDRq8xSz1D@YdI2bYIzIiPi8StKwGz@4n2T5033fa1D/I4UQba36ambUMsPvymVGl5pyRstvNGTd3p4R5MrGq6M5IMRPpjJJzN8YskNCzc8uePhzuN16uX6n2t9AA)

Each program ends after the `where`  except the last which just ends.

Here it is in a more readable manner.

```hs
main=a
a=a where
  a=b
  main=main
  b=b where
    b=c
    main=main
    c=c where
      c=d
      main=main
      d=d where 
        d=e
        main=main
        e=e where
          e=f
          main=main
          f=f where
            f=g
            main=main
            g=g where 
              g=h
              main=main
              h=h where
                h=i
                main=main
                i=i where
                  i=pure()
                  main=main
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU5JDsMgDLznFXNsH@HHOGAWNamqVFWfT0NIEVsuxrMax@@HLEsIK/sn8cTE@DrZZAKY5n0eQhz7PtOc1YjU8ZYOQJEqPBHrc6t9gCadnDiJSEneWzsgJFV14kyB@gxgyHSpyNoKj5KAJdt@8S@4hhkXAI7c4HxSfMddtQCe/EVP1F6fTW73gZQLQ/gB)

## Explanation

The idea here is to use variable shadowing to create a chain of assignments.  If the chain is broken the shadow
means that we switch and define the variable in terms of itself an form a loop.

This is easier to see for just two programs.

```hs
main=a;a=a where a=pure();main=main
```

With just the first program

```hs
main=a;a=a where
```

`a` is a loop so `main` is a loop.  But when we add the second `a` gets shadowed and now `a` is a halting program.
We do this several times each time changing the variable names so that the nothing can shadow something it is not supposed to.

Answer (score 4):

## [Lost](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Lost), Score 2, 5 bytes

```
/%
@/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8kvLvn/X1@Vy0H//38A)

The programs are

```
/%
```

and

```
@/
```

This works because any lost program that halts must have both `%` and `@`. Since `%` turns off the safety to allow halting and `@` actually does it.  The simpler `%@` doesn't work because half the time the pointer is moving vertically and can only hit one of the two.  In fact in order to *always* halt a lost program needs some kind of redirect in every column and row (technically there are some specific exceptions to this but lets not get into them), meaning that this is certainly the smallest program that always halts.

So we can't go shorter for score 2. But ...

## [Lost](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Lost), Score 3, 5 bytes

```
%^
@>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8kvLvn/XzWOy8Hu/38A)

... we can increase the score at no cost to bytes!

The programs here are:

```
%^
```

```
@>
```

The second one being a single newline.

This is one of the specific exceptions to the one redirect in every row and column rule.  It's the same length, but both of our redirects are in the same column since the other column automatically terminates by itself.

A program needs both `%` and `@` to halt at all so any program missing one of the first two mustn't halt.  So we only need to check the case where program 2 is missing.

```
%^@>
```

Here there is no possible path from the `%` to the `@`.  The redirects ensure it.  So there is no way for this program to halt.

And of course this can't be beat since you can't make a shorter halting program.

## [Lost](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Lost), Score 4, 7 bytes

```
%\<
<@^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8kvLvn/XzXGhsvGIe7/fwA)

Nothing much special here it's a modified version of the above.  There might be a smaller program that scores 4.  I'm not sure.

The programs here are

```
%
```

```
\
```

```
<
```

```
<@^
```

Once again since a program *needs* `%` and `@` to work so we have only to check

```
%<@^
```

```
%/<@^
```

```
%<
<@^
```

None of which halt.

## [Lost](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Lost), Score 10, 19 bytes

```
%<ABCDE\<
<<<<<<<@^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8kvLvn/X9XG0cnZxTXGhssGAhzi/v//rxsGAA)

And here we have an extensible solution, adding 2 bytes for every 1 score (until we run out of noop bytes).  It is modified from the score 4 solution.  The programs are

```
%<
```

*Each letter is 1 program for 5 total*

```
\
```

```
<
```

```
<<<<<<
```

```
<@^
```

The first and last program are necessary because they have the `%` and `%`.  Without the newline we will have something like

```
%<...<@^
```

Which can never have a path from `%` to `@`, so the newline is needed too.  We can also treat the letters as interchangeable since they are all noops, so we are only concerned with *how many* letters are present.  At this point we can say that the only way for a program made from these to halt is if `/` is exactly above the `@`.  Since it can't approach from the left or the right due to `<` and `^`, and there is no other way to get a vertical direction on the first row.  This tells us that `/` must be present, but also gives us a quick way of checking the programs.

Unfortunately there are still quite a few programs to check. In fact more than I think I want to list in this post. The checks are easy given what I've already shown so please have a go yourself if you doubt my work.

Answer (score 4):

## Lenguage, 10 programs, 2324143350556659959 bytes

```
     -[]++++++++++++++++++
      --[]++++++++++++++++
        --[]++++++++++++++
          --[]++++++++++++
            --[]++++++++++
              --[]++++++++
                --[]++++++
                  --[]++++
                    --[]++
+)                    -.[]
---------------------------
     >+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+<[]
     201010101010101010367
```

Lacking the i-th program (\$i \in [2,10]\$), `>+-+-+-++[]` pattern appears (`-[]` when i=2).

Lacking the first several programs, `->+-+-+-+<[]` pattern is still an infinite loop, or `-.[]` if only the 10th one left, still infloop

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes, 2 programs.

### #1

```
{
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=5&code=%7B&inputs=&header=&footer=) Simple forever loop. The `5` flag makes it terminate after 5 seconds so it doesn't jam up the interpreter.

### #2

```
0|{
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=5&code=0%7C%7B&inputs=&header=&footer=)  Another simple loop.

### Halting program

```
{0|{
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%7B0%7C%7B&inputs=&header=&footer=)

This works because `|` is a branch in structure when in a structure, but does nothing when in the main scope. So in the second one, it pushes 0 then executes a forever loop, but in here, it executes a loop containing a forever loop with 0 as the condition, so the inside loop is never run and the program halts.

Note that like TIO, the Vyxal interpreter times out after 60 seconds to avoid breaking, but if that was removed these two would run forever.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 19 bytes / 3 programs

### #1

```
`{`{`
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=5&code=%60%7B%60%7B%60&inputs=&header=&footer=)

### #2

```
{`{`
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=5&code=%7B%60%7B%60&inputs=&header=&footer=)

### #3

```
`0|}0|{`{`
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=5&code=%600%7C%7D0%7C%7B%60%7B%60%0A&inputs=&header=&footer=)

### Concatenated

```
`{`{`{`{``0|}0|{`{`
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=5&code=%60%7B%60%7B%60%7B%60%7B%60%600%7C%7D0%7C%7B%60%7B%60&inputs=&header=&footer=)

A quite different approach to what I had before.

With NOPS removed, it becomes:

```
{        # While...
 {  }    # While
  0      # 0
   |     # Do nothing
     0   # 0
      |  # Do..
       { # Forever loop, never executed
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Scala Interpreter], 10+ programs, 265 bytes

This challenge is impossible to solve in languages that require a global program body around their code.

Luckily, Scala *Interpreter* is a way to bypass this issue :)

However, the challenge is still hard to solve in a language that requires to declare variables before using them and that does not provide a simple global mutable context to share information between the subprograms. However, the necessary information sharing can be achieved indirectly by affecting the global state of the JVM.

So, here are the 10 programs (one per line). Of course, it can be extended to any number of programs:

```scala
new java.util.Timer("1");
new java.util.Timer("2");
new java.util.Timer("3");
new java.util.Timer("4");
new java.util.Timer("5");
new java.util.Timer("6");
new java.util.Timer("7");
new java.util.Timer("8");
new java.util.Timer("9");
while(Thread.activeCount!=10){};sys.exit
```

**Explanation**: Every instantiation of a new Timer creates a new background thread that prevents the program from stopping. Further, the 10th program runs forever if the number of threads (incl. main thread) is not 10. Thus, the total number of threads is the indirectly affected "global variable" here.

No concatenation of 1..9 programs halts, for example:

- `scala -e 'new java.util.Timer("2");'`
- `scala -e 'new java.util.Timer("1");new java.util.Timer("5");'`
- `scala -e 'while(Thread.activeCount!=10){};sys.exit'`
- `scala -e 'new java.util.Timer("4");while(Thread.activeCount!=10){};sys.exit'`

Only when concatenating all 10 sub-programs, the resulting program will halt.

You can try out this behavior in TIO:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ddC9DoJAEATg3qdYqaAB8d8YC2NlYSUvcMImtwQPvFv@Qnj28@y9ZjLJl0wxJheVsPWrxJzhIUgBDoyqMHBtGpggSUDVjMBSsAsyIFEUqME1B6Dx05LGAl4jPH9bcFeMutHo0irsoRSdiFumKs7ojToM0iBa/IW1DzY@2Ppg54O9Dw4@OPrg5KCXVGGYSe1OiUXO1OGtbhUvL@kqmuazGU2MA7Gd7Rc)

This approach does also work via Copy&Paste into the Scala REPL or to some Scala IDE, but then you need to replace the literal `10` by `11`, since in this case another JVM thread is running in the background :)

Comment: You could replace two of these with just `new java.util.Timer()` and `new java.util.Timer("")`, and `!=10` can be `<10` I think

Answer (score 3):

## TypeScript Types, 10 programs, 630 bytes

```ts
interface X{a:keyof{b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j}extends keyof X?0:X["a"]}
interface X{b:keyof{a,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j}extends keyof X?0:X["b"]}
interface X{c:keyof{a,b,d,e,f,g,h,i,j}extends keyof X?0:X["c"]}
interface X{d:keyof{a,b,c,e,f,g,h,i,j}extends keyof X?0:X["d"]}
interface X{e:keyof{a,b,c,d,f,g,h,i,j}extends keyof X?0:X["e"]}
interface X{f:keyof{a,b,c,d,e,g,h,i,j}extends keyof X?0:X["f"]}
interface X{g:keyof{a,b,c,d,e,f,h,i,j}extends keyof X?0:X["g"]}
interface X{h:keyof{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,i,j}extends keyof X?0:X["h"]}
interface X{i:keyof{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,j}extends keyof X?0:X["i"]}
interface X{j:keyof{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i}extends keyof X?0:X["j"]}
```

[Try It Online!](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strict=false&noImplicitAny=false#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBoG84C4DWECeA9jOgEYA0C5AJuROTOQObkAW5w5AVgL4QAekENQDOyPERhoA-AAYsqANoAiOMoC6PAFChIsRCgylcBYpko06DZmw7c+giMLETiM+UuWkN23dHhIaOgIJpLmFLT0jCzsnLwCQqLiplKocgoqCD464P4GQdShZnDkFFRRNrH2CU5JrqnpntTZfvqBGBBFJCVlltG2cQ6JLinuGcoQLblthugwXeEWkZV28Y7OyZJjnjBTegGzTAs9S1aMVWvDm25pHipMe3nt6KzHpacVLIM1G-XbKqxHjMgsA3r1lv12JdaiMtrdxsAgQcglwwR9rDEOEMYdcGndlFwfEA)
([with one program removed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strict=false&noImplicitAny=false#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBoG84C4DWECeA9jOgEYA0C5AJuROTOQObkAW5w5AVgL4QAekENQDOyPERhoA-AAYsqANoAiOMoC6PAFChIsRCgylcBYpko06DZmw7c+giMLETiM+UuWkN23dHhIaOgIJpLmFLT0jCzsnLwCQqLiplKocgoqCD464P4GQdShZnDkFFRRNrH2CU5JrqnpntTZfvqBGBBFJCVlltG2cQ6JLinuGcoQLblthugwXeEWkZV28Y7OyZJjnjBTegGzTAs9S1aMVWvDm25pHipM2QD0j60HQazHpacVLIM1G-VtipWHs8u10MBPr1lv12JdaiMtrdxsBQTMglwod9rDEOEMEdcGndlFwfEA))

Each line is its own program, and newlines between the programs are optional.

"Does not halt" is hard to define in TypeScript Types, so this uses the closest analog: a type that resolves to itself, resulting in an infinite loop.

Technically, the 'interpreter' still halts, but with an error; if this is problematic, than this program can be considered to be written in TypeScript Types*, which is like TypeScript Types except any errors cause the 'interpreter' to never halt.

Note that this requires the flag `noImplicitAny: false`; this is the default in `tsc` itself, but not in the playground.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 96 bytes, score 10

```
Ｗα«≔⁻αAαＷα«≔⁻αBαＷα«≔⁻αCαＷα«≔⁻αDαＷα«≔⁻αEαＷα«≔⁻αFαＷα«≔⁻αGαＷα«≔⁻αHαＷα«≔⁻αIαＷα«≔⁻αJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZα
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///9nu3nNh5a/ahzyqPG3ec2Op7biCbihCHijCHigiHiiiHihiHijiHigSHiiSHi5e3j6@cfEBgUHBIaFh4RGXVu4///AA) Explanation: Each loop subtracts a different substring of the predefined uppercase alphabet, so the program will only finish if all of the letters get subtracted. The programs can of course be concatenated in any order. As ten separate programs:

```
Ｗα«≔⁻αAα
Ｗα«≔⁻αBα
Ｗα«≔⁻αCα
Ｗα«≔⁻αDα
Ｗα«≔⁻αEα
Ｗα«≔⁻αFα
Ｗα«≔⁻αGα
Ｗα«≔⁻αHα
Ｗα«≔⁻αIα
Ｗα«≔⁻αJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZα
```

This can be trivially extended to 26 programs by subtracting each letter separately. Furthermore, this can be trivially extended to 95 programs by subtracting from the whole printable ASCII character set instead of just the uppercase alphabet. (It might even be possible to extend this up to 150 programs by mixing the approaches.)

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 10 programs, <s>275</s> 256 bytes

```julia
!x=while x<1end
e+=1
!01
!x=while x*e<4end
e+=1
!01
!x=while x*e<5end
e+=1
!01
!x=while x*e<6end
e+=1
!01
!x=while x*e<7end
e+=1
!01
!x=while x*e<8end
e+=1
!01
!x=while x*e<9end
e+=1
!01
!x=while x*e<10end
e+=1
!01
!x=while x*e<11end
e+=1
!01
while e<11end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@/9fscK2PCMzJ1WhwsYwNS@FK1Xb1pBL0QCI4RJaqTYmuKVMcUuZ4ZYyxy1lgVvKEreUoQEeOVSfQSSgwv//AwA)

[ry it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@//fkEuxwrY8IzMnVaFCK9XGJDUvhStV2xYobIAmZYpbygy3lDluKQvcUpa4pQwN8MgZoshBJKDC//8DAA)

[Try it line!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@/9fscK2PCMzJ1WhwsYwNS@FK1Xb1pBL0QCI4RJaqTYmuKVMcUuZ4ZayxC1laIBHDtWNEAmo8P//AA)

[Try it onlin!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@/9fscK2PCMzJ1WhwsYwNS@FK1Xb1pBL0QCI4RJaqTYmuKVMcUuZ4ZYyxy1lgVvKEreUoQEeOWSf/f8PAA)

the separation between the programs is between each `!0` and `1`

uses Julia 0.6 to be able to redefine `e` (the euler constant)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 10 programs, <s>156</s> 151 bytes

```r
while(T<-T*2)1-while(T<-T^2)1-while(T<-T*3)1-while(T<-T*4)1-while(T<-T*5)1-while(T<-T*6)1-while(T<-T*7)1-while(T<-T*8)1-while(T<-T*9)1-while(T<-T<6e5)1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/vzwjMydVI8RGN0TLSNNQF8GNQ@VqGaNyTVC5pqhcM1SuOSrXApVricK1MUsFGvb/PwA)

### Separate programs:

```r
while(T<-T*2)1
while(T<-T^2)1
-while(T<-T*3)1
-while(T<-T*4)1
-while(T<-T*5)1
-while(T<-T*6)1
-while(T<-T*7)1
-while(T<-T*8)1
-while(T<-T*9)1
-while(T<-T<6e5)1
```

The full program works by starting with T (which starts at `TRUE` and becomes 1 when used arithmetically) and then multiplied by each number from 2 to 9 as well as squaring it (after `T<-T*2`). The last program compares T to 6e5, at which point all of the comparisons will equal 0.

Separately, no combination of programs will ever reach 0 since anything excluding the last program will just head for +infinity, while any combination including the last program will evaluate to `TRUE` unless all of the prior programs were present.

If any subsequence without the first program did complete its `while` loop, the unary minus would throw an error, but since they never do, no error is generated.

Thanks to @RobinRyder for saving a byte!

Comment: [151 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/vzwjMydVI8RGN0TLSNNQF8GNQ@VqGaNyTVC5pqhcM1SuOSrXApVricK1MUsFGvb/PwA "R – Try It Online") by replacing `T*10` by `T^2`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Forte](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Forte), 10 programs, 96 bytes

```
9LET0=1
10LET1=2
11LET2=3
12LET3=4
13LET4=5
14LET5=6
15LET6=7
16LET7=8
17LET8=21
20LET21=0
21END
```

Each line is a program, except that the last two lines together constitute the tenth program.

- [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcwpDoBAEARA36/Znj0R7VhHUHwBLAnh/8PgStV1P@/pvmzzSCKYApSBDJgyaIGsAuZAUQVLoKqBNdDUwRboGmAPDBlhf2RUgnHuq/sH)
- [ry it online!](https://tio.run/##FcwrDoAwEARQP6fpbL9mHHUE1SuAJSHcf1ncU@@6n/d0Z9rnogxkwJRBC2QVMAeKKlgCVQ2sgaYOtkDXAHtgyAj7I6MSjPPY3D8)
- [Try it onlin!](https://tio.run/##DcYpEoBAEANAn9dsZk9EJA7JF8BSRfH/Ia36ft7vytyO/SwiWBwqQDqhCoZT1cDqNHWwOV0D7M7QBIcztcDpLAWR@QM)
- [Try t online!](https://tio.run/##FcspDoBAEARA36/Znj0R7VhHUHwBLAnh/8PgytR1P@/pvmzzSCKYApSBDJgyaIGsApZAVQNroKmDLdA1wB4YMsL@b1SCce6r@wc)
- [e!](https://tio.run/##S8svKkn9/9/IwMc1xMjQ1oDLyNDVz@X/fwA)

#### Explanation

Forte is a language built around redefining numbers. Execution control is achieved by redefining line numbers, thereby shuffling statements around.

The only way to exit is via the `END` statement. So right off the bat, if the tenth program is missing, there is no way to exit and the program loops forever.

If the tenth program is present but one of the earlier programs is missing, the `LET` statement on line 20 redefines the number 21 to be some value between 0 and 8 (depending on which of lines 9 through 16 were able to run). Since this number is less than the current line number of 20, the `END` statement moves to before the instruction pointer and is never executed. The program proceeds to loop infinitely.

If all ten programs are present, lines 9 through 17 redefine 0 (through a series of steps) to equal 21. Then line 20 redefines 21 to equal 21 (no change). Execution proceeds to line 21, which ends the program.

<sup>(I'm not sure whether all implementations of Forte will behave this way, but [Forter](https://github.com/judofyr/forter), the version on TIO, does. This behavior seems to be in line with the description in the Esolangs article, too.)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 10+ programs, 184 bytes

```perl
BEGIN{s//t/}{redo}BEGIN{s//i/}{redo}BEGIN{s//x/}{redo}BEGIN{s//4/}{redo}BEGIN{y/4/5/}{redo}BEGIN{y/5/6/}{redo}BEGIN{y/6/7/}{redo}BEGIN{y/7/8/}{redo}BEGIN{y/8/e/}{redo}BEGIN{eval}{redo}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/9/J1d3Tr7pYX79Ev7a6KDUlvxYukokhUoEhYoIqUgkUMEUXMtU3Qxcy0zdHFzLXt0AXstBPRRVKLUvMgQr8/w8A)

With newlines added for readability:

```perl
BEGIN{s//t/}{redo}
BEGIN{s//i/}{redo}
BEGIN{s//x/}{redo}
BEGIN{s//4/}{redo}
BEGIN{y/4/5/}{redo}
BEGIN{y/5/6/}{redo}
BEGIN{y/6/7/}{redo}
BEGIN{y/7/8/}{redo}
BEGIN{y/8/e/}{redo}
BEGIN{eval}{redo}
```

`{redo}` is a short infinite loop in perl. `BEGIN` blocks run before everything else, so all we need to do is exit from a `BEGIN` block.

To do this, we build the string `exit` and then `eval` it in a `BEGIN` block. `s//whatever/` is a concise way to prepend `whatever` to the global variable `$_`, and then `eval` evaluates that string. The first four programs set `$_` to `4xit` and then the next programs use the transliteration operator `y///` to successively change the `4` to various other numbers and finally to `e`.

Anything besides `exit` will do nothing when `eval` is run, and of course removing `eval` will keep the program from exiting, so the program will run forever.

This method can be extended to an arbitrary number of programs with additional uses of `y///` and `s///`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 10 progs, 27 bytes, take 3.

```
{`{
{1
{2
{3
{4
{5
{6
{7
{8
`L17<|`{
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%7B%60%7B%7B1%7B2%7B3%7B4%7B5%7B6%7B7%7B8%60L17%3C%7C%60%7B&inputs=&header=&footer=)

I finally figured out what the others are doing. This basically checks if the string between the backticks' length is 17, and if not loops forever.

No trailing newlines, they're just formatted like this for readability.

Any character except `X` and `|` can be used instead of the digits.

Comment: @AaronMiller The challenge requires the programs to be distinct.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg Whoops, missed that. [23 bytes, 10 programs](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=5&code=%7B%60%E2%88%9E%7B%7B1%7B2%7B3%7B4%7B5%7B6%7B%60L15%E2%89%A0%7C&inputs=&header=%23%20The%2010%20programs%20are%3A%0A%23%20%7B%60%0A%23%20%E2%88%9E%0A%23%20%7B%0A%23%20%7B1%0A%23%20%7B2%0A%23%20%7B3%0A%23%20%7B4%0A%23%20%7B5%0A%23%20%7B6%0A%23%20%7B%60L15%E2%89%A0%7C&footer=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 36 bytes, score 6

```
≔⁰ψＷα«≔⁰αＷβ«≔⁰βＷγ«≔⁰γＷφ«≔⁰φＷχ«≔⁰χＷψ«
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5//9R55RHjRvOd7zfs/3cxkOrIdxzG0HcTXDuJhB3M5y7Gcg93wbjnm8Dcdvh3HYQt@PQ6v//AQ) Explanation: This is the concatenation of six six-byte programs. Each program sets a predefined variable to zero and then loops over another predefined variable. This means that no program will finish except for the concatenation of all six, which will ensure that all of the predefined variables are set to zero, causing all of the loops to terminate. (Concatenating the programs in a different order won't work because the first program will prevent the final program's loop from executing, preventing further programs from clearing the first program's loop variable.) As six separate programs:

```
≔⁰ψＷα«
≔⁰αＷβ«
≔⁰βＷγ«
≔⁰γＷφ«
≔⁰φＷχ«
≔⁰χＷψ«
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net), 10+ programs; <s>342</s> <s>134</s> <s>127</s> <s>124</s> <s>123</s> 116 bytes.

Byte count for PHP assumes you don't require and count the 8 characters of the surrounding `<?php ?>` tags for each program; if so, add 80 bytes.

```
while(!file(__FILE__)[9]);die();
for(;;);
foR(;;);
fOr(;;);
fOR(;;);
For(;;);
FoR(;;);
FOr(;;);
FOR(;;);
while(1);
```

I realized that `FOR` is case-insensitive, so I could use seven more unique `for`s, saving 7 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 114 bytes, 10 programs

```ruby
1/($.-40)while 99while$.+=11while$.+=07while$.+=06while$.+=05while$.+=04while$.+=03while$.+=02while$.+=01while$.=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/31BfQ0VP18RAszwjMydVwdISTKvoadsaGsKZBuYIphmCaYpgmiCYxgimEYIJM8zW8P9/AA)

The programs break down like this:

```ruby
1/($.-40)while 9
```

```ruby
9while$.+=1
```

```ruby
1while$.+=0
```

```ruby
7while$.+=0
```

...

```ruby
1while$.=1
```

The `1/($.-40)` causes a `ZeroDivisionError` if all the other snippets successfully incremented the counter `$.` to `40`, breaking out of all of the loops. If any parts are missing, `$.` will be less than `40` and the division will work, so the program will continue to loop.

Because the inner loop never terminates, the outer loops can never increment `$.` more than once, so there's no opportunity for `$.` to reach 40 except if all the programs are there.

[Try nline!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/31BfQ0VP18RAszwjMydVwdISTKvoadsaGsKZBqYIpgmCaYxgGiGYMG22hv//AwA)

[y it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/37I8IzMnVUVP29bQEM40MEcwzRBMUwTTBME0RjCNEEyYYbaG//8DAA)

[Tre!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/31BfQ0VP18RAszwjMydVwdIQTKvo2Rr@/w8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Klein](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Klein) 000, Score 10, 17 bytes

```
ABCDEFG\
....!><@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y85Jzcz7/9/RydnF1c09hksPCBTtbBz@//9vYGAAAA)

This is a modification of [my lost answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226845/56656) so to get a good idea of how this works I recommend reading that explanation.  Since Klein is not a language designed to torture the programmer, this ends up being 2 bytes shorter.

The programs are:

*The 7 letters*

```
\
```

*(Just a newline)*

```
....!><@
```

This works of an alignment principle. The `/` has to be above the `@` or you are not going to reach it.  There are some special bits `!><` for example is a trap that catches anything going rightwards, which is there for when the newline is removed.

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge-93](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), 10 programs, 13 bytes

```
~1\-2*4+7`#@_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/v84wRtdIy0TbPEHZIf5/HZchVwyXLpcRlxaXCZc2F0iUK/4/AA)

I think there's at least one more byte that can golfed off this. 9 of the programs are one byte apiece, with the last being `` 7`#@ ``. The initial `~1\-2*4+` generates the number `8`, with any lesser combination generating a smaller number. This then uses the `` 7`#@_ `` to only terminate if the number is bigger than 7. Note that if the `` 7`#@ `` section is removed, the program has no way to terminate, and if the `_` is removed, there is no way for the pointer to travel left, and therefore no way to execute the `@`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 10 programs, <s>179</s> 175 bytes

```perl
END{{redo}}use POSIX;END{{redo}}s//)/;END{{redo}}s//0/;END{{redo}}s//(/;END{{redo}}s//_exit/;END{{redo}}s//::/;END{{redo}}s//SIX/;END{{redo}}s//O/;END{{redo}}s//P/;eval;{redo}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/9/Vz6W6uig1Jb@2trQ4VSHAP9gzwhpJsFhfX1MfTcAAXUADXSA@tSKzBF3QygpdBGgXupA/ukCAvnVqWWKONUTk/38A)

For readability, here's the same program with newlines:

```perl
END{{redo}}use POSIX;
END{{redo}}s//)/;
END{{redo}}s//0/;
END{{redo}}s//(/;
END{{redo}}s//_exit/;
END{{redo}}s//::/;
END{{redo}}s//SIX/;
END{{redo}}s//O/;
END{{redo}}s//P/;
eval;{redo}
```

Builds the string `POSIX::_exit(0)` and evals it. `END` blocks always run at the end of a program even if there was an error, but `POSIX::_exit` skips this.